# How to use SharedPreferences in Achartengine line graph?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to use `SharedPreferences` in the code for `LineGraph`:

```
public class LineGraph{
    Context applicationContext;
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

        // Our first data
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // x values!
        int[] y =  { 30, 34, 45, 57, 77, 89, 100, 111 ,123 ,145 }; // y values!
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1"); 
        for( int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            series.add(x[i], y[i]);
        }

        // Our second data
        int[] x2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // x values!
        int[] y2 =  { 145, 123, 111, 100, 89, 77, 57, 45, 34, 30}; // y values!
        TimeSeries series2 = new TimeSeries("Line2"); 
        for( int i = 0; i < x2.length; i++)
        {
            series2.add(x2[i], y2[i]);
        }

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        dataset.addSeries(series2);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); // Holds a collection of XYSeriesRenderer and customizes the graph
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // This will be used to customize line 1
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // This will be used to customize line 2
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);

        // Customization time for line 1!
        renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        // Customization time for line 2!
        renderer2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
        renderer2.setFillPoints(true);

        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "Line Graph Title");
        return intent;
    }
}
```

But the `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);`
does not work, it stopped the application.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this within your method, not at the class level.

Something like this:

```
public class LineGraph {
    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        // Our first data
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // x values!
        ...
```

The way you had it, applicationContext was always going to be null.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your logcat-output. 
Apart from this I assume that you receive a nullpointer exception when itializing the shared preferences, because the applicationContext-variable is null.

Place the initialization of your shared preferences into the getIntent()-method and pass the context-argument.